# Syslog & Async Handler - Socket Closed

Tags: jboss

I'm trying to add filtering capabilities to a syslog handler in JBoss (EAP 6.1) as the basic handler doesn't support the filter-spec element in standalone.xml configuration. One option appears to create an Async handler to wrap the syslog handler which can then be used to apply the filter:

```
<syslog-handler name="SysLog">
    <server-address value="10.1.2.3"/>
    <app-name value="myapp"/>
    <facility value="log-audit"/>
</syslog-handler>

<async-handler name="SysLogFiltered">
    <filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;.*filter this.*&quot;))" />
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%s%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <queue-length value="128"/>
    <subhandlers>
        <handler name="SysLog"/>
    </subhandlers>
</async-handler>
```

But this causes issues when an event is sent to the doPublish method of the syslog handler (notably the syslog handler has previously been told to close):

```
00:53:07,738 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1) java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 1: Publication error
00:53:07,739 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: The syslog handler has been closed.
00:53:07,740 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.SyslogHandler.doPublish(SyslogHandler.java:485)
00:53:07,741 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publish(ExtHandler.java:76)
00:53:07,741 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.AsyncHandler$AsyncTask.run(AsyncHandler.java:199)
00:53:07,742 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration, or any other ideas for how messages can be filtered prior to being sent to the syslog handler

Comment: Did you find the cause of the problem? I'm struggling with the same issue whereas I'm not filtering. I get the exception on the first try of the syslog-handler to write a log message on a RSyslog-UDP-Socket directly after jboss startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ultimately i had to use a custom-handler to get this working:

```
<custom-handler name="syslog"
        class="org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.SyslogHandler"
        module="org.jboss.as.logging">

    <filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;.*filter this.*&quot;))" />

    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%s%n"/>
    </formatter>

    <properties>
        <property name="appName" value="jboss"/>
        <property name="serverHostname" value="${syslog.server}"/>
        <property name="facility" value="LOG_AUDIT"/>
    </properties>
</custom-handler>
```